# How to get any frame from a video used MediaCodec?

Tags: android, video, frame, gif, android-mediacodec

I just want to get frames(bitmap) from a video in android.
Just like a method:

 `MediaCodecUtil.getFrameAt(long timeUs,Object otherParams);`

I have query some blog,And I found `MediaCodec` is a good choose to do that.
but,how to do?Anyone help?

Comment: whats wrong with `android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever` ?

Comment: @pskink `MediaMetadataRetriever` it's slow,if i want take one frame,it's will be a good choose,but i want all frames of video.it's slowly.any other way? thx

Comment: all frames? what for?

Comment: @pskink not really get all frames, some like get frame at any time.like a method `MediaCodecUtil.getFrameAt(long timeUs,Object otherParams);`

Comment: there is no such class `MediaCodecUtil` in the android sdk, so i have no idea how it is implemented

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the easiest way will be to use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and set its output Surface to be [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html)'s Surface.

[MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) will parse the video file, seek to the relevant frame, and decode it for you.